# How to move recursive files from one directory to another and same name files rename the older one appending its modification time

Tags: sed, find, mv, inode, stat

I need to move recursively all the files from one drive to another and the same path/name files rename if different the older by appending to the file name the modification time. Same path/name files overwrite.
The sizes of the files vary between 5K to 500M.

Here is a tree of the testing environment I have created and some comments:

```
/bmrlbackup/drive1/
`-- user001
    `-- directory1
        `-- project001
            |-- file000           #identical
            |-- file001           #older same name
            |-- file0011          #unique
            |-- phase1
            |   |-- file000       #identical
            |   |-- file110       #unique
            |   |-- file999       #newer same name
            |   `-- phase11
            |       `-- file111   #unique
            `-- phase2
                `-- file120       #unique
/bmrlbackup/drive2/
`-- user002
    `-- directory2
        `-- project001
            |-- file000           #identical
            |-- file001           #newer same name
            |-- file0012          #unique
            |-- phase1
            |   |-- file000       #identical
            |   |-- file210       #unique
            |   `-- file999       #older same name
            `-- phase2
                |-- file220       #unique
                `-- phase21
                    `-- file221   #unique
```

The output for the rsync to move the unique files:

```
#rsync -a --ignore-existing --remove-source-files $sd1/ $dd1/
project001/
project001/file0011
project001/phase1/
project001/phase1/file110
project001/phase1/phase11/
project001/phase1/phase11/file111
project001/phase2/
project001/phase2/file120
```

The remaining files to be moved:

```
#remm="ls -1 $(find $sd1/ -type f)"
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/file000
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/file001
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/phase1/file000
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/phase1/file999
```

Here, there are files which are the same in both locations and need to be moved and overwrite the destination:

```
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/file000 
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/phase1/file000
```

And here there are files which have the same name but different content:

```
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/file001
/bmrlbackup/drive1/user001/directory1/project001/phase1/file999
```

The "same name different content" files need to be compared and the older one needs to be moved renamed appended with the modification date&time, so if source is newer then append the name of destination file and move the source, and if the source is older, then append the name of the source and move the name appended source.

The resultant of this process will eventually move all the files from drive1 to drive2.

Please, please, please HELP !!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use "diff" to compare FILES line by line. also look at this post [find mtime](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/88525/need-to-move-files-to-different-folder-based-on-the-creation-date). Then you can use the mv command to move the older file

Comment: find mtime implies a known range of time, and this is not the case.

Comment: How about :
               if [ −n "$(find file1 −prune −newer file2)" ]; then
                   printf %s\\n "file1 is newer than file2"
               fi   I found this at the find man

Answer (score 0):

Use rsync with --update and --backup in both directions:

```
-u, --update                skip files that are newer on the receiver
-b, --backup                make backups (see --suffix & --backup-dir)
```